# Cannot mock/spy class java.util.Optional

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to implement this JUnit code:

```
private BinlistsService binlistsService = Mockito.mock(BinlistsService.class);

@Mock
Optional<BinLists> binList = null;

@BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {

        BinLists binLists = new BinLists();
        binLists.setId(1);
        ....

        binList = Optional.of(binLists);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() {

        when(binlistsService.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(binList);

}
```

But I get this error stack:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class java.util.Optional
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
    at org.data
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: you don't need any `mock` for `Optional`

Comment: ok, how I can solve the issue? Can you show me code example, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `@Mock` on the `Optional<BinLists>` field.

`Optional` is a simple class that can be easily created and controlled by you, so you do not need to mock it .Just create an actual instance when you need it which you already do it in `beforeEachTest()` :

```java
private BinlistsService binlistsService = Mockito.mock(BinlistsService.class);

Optional<BinLists> binList = null;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {

        BinLists binLists = new BinLists();
        binLists.setId(1);
        ....

        binList = Optional.of(binLists);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() {

        when(binlistsService.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(binList);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need mock for `class Optional` (java core class **final**), you need mock  for `class BinLists`

```
    @Mock
    BinLists binList = null;
```

JUnit can`t mock the final class, but if you need this unusual technique of mocking can use **PowerMock** https://github.com/powermock/powermock

Comment: I think you wanted to say `Mockito` instead of `JUnit can't mock the final class`, but that wouldn't be true either. With a recent version of `Mockito` you can [enable final mocking](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39).

Comment: I've been testing Mockito lately, but I haven't reached that feature, excellent information. I will try it!