# How to mock an SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockito, instrumented-test

I am trying to mock an SQLiteOpenHelper class in instrumented tests so whenever any fragment tries to get information from the database it returns a generic result. However, I keep getting an error saying:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  Cannot mock/spy class
> com.example.cleaningschedule.helpers.DatabaseHandler Mockito cannot
> mock/spy because :
>
> - final class
>   at com.example.cleaningschedule.ToDoListInstrumentedTest.oneTask(ToDoListInstrumentedTest.kt:81)

The test class is:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ToDoListInstrumentedTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    private fun getActivity() = activityRule.activity

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().deleteDatabase("TaskDatabase")
    }

    @Test
    fun oneTask() {
        val mock = mock(DatabaseHandler::class.java)
        `when`(mock.getTasks()).thenThrow()

        onView(withId(R.id.taskName)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

The class I am trying to mock is:

```
class DatabaseHandler(context: Context): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    companion object {
    private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 5
    private const val DATABASE_NAME = "TaskDatabase"
        ...
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        ...
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        ...
    }    
    fun getTasks(): MutableList<Pair<MutableList<String>, MutableList<Room>>> {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have looked at several other similar questions but none have helped:

- [Error mocking Class which hold reference to SQLiteOpenHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768644/error-mocking-class-which-hold-reference-to-sqliteopenhelper)
- [Mock final class in java using mockito library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181831/mock-final-class-in-java-using-mockito-library) - I had a lot of issues with import PowerMock
- [How to mock a final class with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito) - I have added the dependency and created the file with the `mock-maker-inline` line as suggested in the answers put I still get the same error. I also tried the answer that suggested `Mockito.mock(SomeMockableType.class,AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(someInstanceThatIsNotMockableOrSpyable))` but this gave me a 'Not enough information to infer type variable T' error
- [Mock final class with Mockito 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979402/mock-final-class-with-mockito-2)
- [Mockito cannot mock/spy because : Final Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577137/mockito-cannot-mock-spy-because-final-class)
- [Cannot mock/spy class java.util.Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633763/cannot-mock-spy-class-java-util-optional)

Comment: Hi, did you see my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I will made an Interface :

```
public interface ContainerHandler {
    MutableList<Pair<MutableList<String>, MutableList<Room>>> getTasks();
}
```

Then I made DatabaseHandler inherit this interface,  I call Mockito's mock function with the Interface.

```
val mock = mock(ContainerHandler::class.java)
    `when`(mock.getTasks()).thenThrow()
```

And finally I inject my mock into the tested class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am not sure how to make an interface of the class. I tried wrapping the the class in an interface but then I can't find the function `getTasks()`. I tried creating a separate interface and then implementing the interface in the `DatabaseHandler` class but this still gives me the same error as before

Comment: I modify my answer to add more precision. Sorry, I'm not behin my computer 

Comment: Thank you, I understand this better now. Doing this stops the error but the `getTasks()` function doesn't actually get mocked when testing the app so the `getTasks()` function is called as normal.